# What is the easiest way to share/listen to music from one device with 2 headphones?

Tags: headphones, mobile-phone, music, mp3-player

I am trying to work out the easiest setup for listening to music from one device via two headphones. My friend and I like the same music but prefer headphones to earphones (which are kind of gross to share anyway) but don't like annoying other people with our music. I suppose a wired or non wired solution should be ok eg. via bluetooth pairing? We usually store all our music on our phone.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have looked online for a solution but haven't found anything yet and so thought maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing. I couldn't even find too many images of people sharing headphones so maybe we're just weird and no one does this except us?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can daisy chain headphones, or use passive splitters, like this one I found on amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B088686SKJ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088686SKJ)

Comment: Perfect thanks. Can multiple splitters be chained together to connect more than 2 headphones at a time too? I couldn't find that specified on the amazon page

Comment: As long as your headphone jack can provide enough power, yes